# Larvel Update Data from Array with foreachloop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Hello There I need Help To Update on Vehicle Wies on Specific Dates.I'm Attaching Form image and Here is my Controller code.

```
public function add_vehicle_expense(Request $request)
{
  
    $veh = array('veh_reg_num' => $request->veh_reg_num);
    foreach ($veh as $data) {
        print_r($request->date[$data]);
        dd();
        $veh = Sale_report::where('date',$request->date[$data])->where('veh_reg_num', $request->veh_reg_num[$data])->update(['diesel_qty'=> $request->qty[$data], 'diesel_rate'=> $request->rate[$data], 'diesel_amount'=> $request->total_amount[$data], 'other_expense'=> $request->other_exp[$data]]);   
    }
    if ($veh) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('Data Store Successfully');
    }
        //$veh = Sale_report::where('date',$request->date)->where('veh_reg_num', $request->veh_reg_num)->update(['diesel_qty'=> $request->qty, 'diesel_rate'=> $request->rate, 'diesel_amount'=> $request->total_amount, 'other_expense'=> $request->other_exp]);   
    
        /* foreach ($request->date as $reg_num => $key ) {
            $s = Sale_report::where('date',$request->date[$reg_num])->where('veh_reg_num',$request->veh_reg_num[$reg_num])->first();
            $s->diesel_qty          = $request->qty[$reg_num];
            $s->diesel_rate         = $request->rate[$reg_num];
            $s->diesel_amount       = $request->total_amount[$reg_num];
            $s->other_expense       = $request->other_exp[$reg_num];
            $s->update();
        } */
       
    
}
```

[image: vehicle Expense Form View]

I have try to Update Data by matching Each Vehicle Number with Date Some times it Show ErrorException Attempt to read property on int,ErrorException Undefined array key "data"

Comment: If `$request->veh_reg_num` contains the word `data`, then it's going to try to access `$request->date('data')`; Try `Log::info($request->all());` at the top of your function, then check your log file in `storage/logs` to see what is being passed into your request.

Comment: Please add the full error text in your question to help to get an answer for your question

Comment: [2023-01-13 16:53:19] local.INFO: array (
  'date' => 
  array (
    0 => '01-01-2023',
    1 => '01-01-2023',
  ),
  'vehicle_num' => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => 'MNS-1787',
  ), I'm getting Vehicle Number null for First Entry

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach ` if you overwrite its entry point `$veh` within the loop? Does not make much sense.

Comment: Using **foreach** I wanna update all records as shown in my pic without **foreach** I don;t think Thats Work without it @dbf

Comment: @aynber have you seen the log.? Im unable to get first array entry

Comment: So `date` has 2 keys, 0 and 1. So you'd have `$request->date[0]` and `$request->date[1]`

Comment: @aynber How to Overcome this Problem..?

Comment: Your foreach that you've commented out seems like you're on the right track

Comment: @aynber Yes But Thats not Working Because Its Unable to Find record On date and Veh_number .

Comment: You need use `$request->get('veh_reg_num')` for getting `veh_reg_num` parameter from your request

Answer (score 0):

I have Found The Solution of this Problem.
I've use implode function to get all the records with comma. Then I use $datas = explode() function to get record in a specific view  then I use foreach() With  exploded variables as shown blow.
`$array = implode(',' , $request->veh_reg_num); $datas = explode(',' , $array); foreach($datas as $data => $value){ Vehicle::update(['field1'=>$request->veh_reg_num[data], 'field2'=>$request->qty[$data],....) }`

Comment: This answer could use a little bit of formatting to help readers.